# How to know which line of a TextView the user has tapped on

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, uitextview

I'm building an app that has a multi-line text editor (UITextView in UIKit, and TextEditor in SwiftUI). When the user tap on any line of the multi-line text, I should know which line is that, so I can print that line or do any other task.

Is there a way to know which line of a UITextView the user has tapped on (using `textViewDidChangeSelection` delegate function or anything else)?

I was thinking of storing the whole text in an Array (each line is an element), and updating the array continuously, but the problem still exists, how shall I know which line has been tapped on to update the array accordingly?

**Note:** I'm using Attributed Strings to give every line different styling.

Comment: It's not going to be easy.  You need to use the `selectedRange` method for sure.

Comment: Would you please post an elaborated answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 5 UIKit Solution:**

Try to add tap gesture to textView and detect the word tapped:

```
let textView: UITextView = {
let tv = UITextView()
tv.text = "ladòghjòdfghjdaòghjjahdfghaljdfhgjadhgf ladjhgf dagf adjhgf adgljdgadsjhladjghl dgfjhdjgh jdahgfljhadlghal dkgjafahd fgjdsfgh adh"
tv.textColor = .black
tv.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
return tv
}()
```

After that in viewDidLoad set tap gesture and constraints:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapResponse(recognizer:)))
textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    
view.addSubview(textView)
textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

now call the function to detect word:

```
@objc func tapResponse(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: textView)
    let position: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
    guard let position2 = textView.closestPosition(to: position) else { return }
    let tapPosition: UITextPosition = position2
    guard let textRange: UITextRange = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition, with: UITextGranularity.word, inDirection: UITextDirection(rawValue: 1)) else {return}
    
    let tappedWord: String = textView.text(in: textRange) ?? ""
    print("tapped word:", tappedWord)
}
```

with Attributed Strings it is the same thing.

**UPDATE**

Add this function to detect line:

```
@objc func didTapTextView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .recognized {
        let location = recognizer.location(ofTouch: 0, in: textView)

        if location.y >= 0 && location.y <= textView.contentSize.height {
            guard let font = textView.font else {
                return
            }

            let line = Int((location.y - textView.textContainerInset.top) / font.lineHeight) + 1
            print("Line is \(line)")
        }
    }
}
```

don't forget to change called function on tap:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapTextView(recognizer:)))
```

**EDIT TO SHOW CURSOR AND SET IT POSITION ON TAP**

to show the cursor on tap location add ended state to recognizer in didTapTextView function set text view is editable and become first responder, this is your didTapTextView function look like:

```
@objc func didTapTextView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
           textView.isEditable = true
           textView.becomeFirstResponder()

           let location = recognizer.location(in: textView)
           if let position = textView.closestPosition(to: location) {
               let uiTextRange = textView.textRange(from: position, to: position)

               if let start = uiTextRange?.start, let end = uiTextRange?.end {
                   let loc = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: position)
                   let length = textView.offset(from: start, to: end)

                   textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(loc, length)
               }
           }
       }
    
    if recognizer.state == .recognized {
        let location = recognizer.location(ofTouch: 0, in: textView)

        if location.y >= 0 && location.y <= textView.contentSize.height {
            guard let font = textView.font else {
                return
            }

            let line = Int((location.y - textView.textContainerInset.top) / font.lineHeight) + 1
            print("Line is \(line)")
        }
    }
}
```

in my example I set cursor color to green to make it much visible, to do it set textView tint color (I added on TextView attributed text):

```
let textView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    
    tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.tintColor = .green // cursor color
    
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "ladòghjòdfghjdaòghjjahdfghaljdfhgjadhgf ladjhgf dagf adjhgf adgljdgadsjhladjghl", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular), .foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " dgfjhdjgh jdahgfljhadlghal dkgjafahd fgjdsfgh adh jsfgjskbfgfs gsfjgbjasfg ajshg kjshafgjhsakhg shf", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold), .foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))
    
    tv.attributedText = attributedString
    
    return tv
}()
```

This is te result:

[image]

Comment: OP asks for SwiftUI,

Comment: @zeytin you're right! Oooooooo escusse me, I don't read well... Have a nice day

Comment: your codes are tidy even if it for Swift, have a nice day bro

Comment: I thought this question is about getting the line number when they tap text.  And where do you go after getting the word they've tapped?

Comment: Great work, but there are 2 problems in your answer, 1. you are printing the word, not the line (or line number) as asked, maybe you should modify `textRange` to identify the line not the word. 2. The cursor and selection are not working properly after modifying the tap gesture in your solution.

Comment: Regarding problem 1, I can change `UITextGranularity.word` to `UITextGranularity.paragraph` to print the whole line (paragraph), but I still need to know the line number. Plus, problem 2.

Comment: @ElTomato Now you can detect the line too.... Have a nice day

Comment: @Fabio Second problem still exists, changing cursor place and selection is not working proberly, I've uploaded a [video](https://imgur.com/1gunYWF) explains the issue... Great work though!

Comment: @Fabio You are the best! Much appreciated :)

Comment: This is completely wrong, as it does not consider that lines will wrap, changing the division calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested out this to the full extent, but here is what you can do: having the selected character range, you can get the generated glyph range like so:

```
let glyphRange = textView.layoutManager.glyphRange(forCharacterRange: selectedRange, 
actualCharacterRange: nil)
```

Now you have a glyph range, and can use `textView.layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments` method to find the line fragment (displayed in text view), corresponding to your glyph range. After this, all that remains is to convert the found glyph range for line fragment to character range using NSLayoutManager's method `characterRange(forGlyphRange, actualGlyphRange:nil)`

This seems to do the trick, although you might need to make adjustments to fit this to your situation (I've tested this on plain text w/o any attributes applied).