# How to show cursor in NSTextView click location - MacOS

Tags: swift, macos

I am working on a macOS application. I want to write a code that shows the cursor on the click location in `NSTextView`. So I searched in StackOverFlow and found [the following code for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057755/how-to-know-which-line-of-a-textview-the-user-has-tapped-on):

```
@objc func didTapTextView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()

        let location = recognizer.location(in: textView)
        if let position = textView.closestPosition(to: location) {
            let uiTextRange = textView.textRange(from: position, to: position)

            if let start = uiTextRange?.start, let end = uiTextRange?.end {
                let loc = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: position)
                let length = textView.offset(from: start, to: end)

                textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(loc, length)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, to convert the code from iOS to macOS, I can:

- Change `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `NSClickGestureRecognizer`
- Change `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` to `textView.window?.makeFirstResponder(textView)`

**The problem is:**

I can't convert the methods `.closestPosition`, `.textRange` and `.offset` to macOS, because they are only available in UIKit, and they return UIKit values like `UITextPosition` and `UITextRange`.

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

To reproduce the problem, just create a document-based Cocoa app (macOS), and add a Scrollable TextView, then the code will be:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        // Set tap gesture
        let singleClickGesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleClickGesture(_:)))
        singleClickGesture.numberOfClicksRequired = 1 // single
        singleClickGesture.delegate = self
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(singleClickGesture)
        // create attributed string
        let myAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
        // Write it to the Text View
        textView.textStorage?.append(myAttrString)
    }
    
    @objc func singleClickGesture(_ recognizer: NSClickGestureRecognizer) {
        // Show cursor and set it to position on tapping
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            textView.isEditable = true
            textView.window?.makeFirstResponder(textView)

        // Comment the next 9 lines to see the problem.
        // TextView is not responding correctly to mouse clicks.
        // The next lines fixes the problem for UIKit (iOS),
        // but I couldn't make equivalent code for Cocoa (macOS).
            let location = recognizer.location(in: textView)
            if let position = textView.closestPosition(to: location) {
                let uiTextRange = textView.textRange(from: position, to: position)
                if let start = uiTextRange?.start, let end = uiTextRange?.end {
                    let loc = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: position)
                    let length = textView.offset(from: start, to: end)
                    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(loc, length)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Solutions?

Comment: What does 'showing the cursor on the click location in NSTextView' mean?

Comment: Because I'm modifying the NSClickGestureRecognizer, cursor does not move to the location of my click within the NSTextView, it will always be shown at the end of the text view

Comment: If you think about it, it shouldn't be difficult.  I can't do it right now as I'm a few hours away from submitting a new app to the store.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is the cursor the I-beam pointer or the flashing insertion point? Aren't the I-beam and the insertion point at the clicked location?

Comment: @Willeke The normal behavior when you click somewhere within the `NSTextView` is the flashing insertion cursor appears in that particular place. But, since I'm modifying the click gesture, this is not happening. So I must write the above manual selection code.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: I've posted a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Are you adding a click recognizer to replace the default behaviour by the same behaviour?

Comment: There is more code inside my click recognizer (like determining the clicked paragraph and line) but I didn't write it in the example above, because it's off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@objc func singleClickGesture(_ recognizer: NSClickGestureRecognizer) {
    // Show cursor and set it to position on tapping
    print("click \(String(describing: NSApp.currentEvent))")
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        textView.isEditable = true
        if let window = textView.window, window.makeFirstResponder(textView) {
            let location = recognizer.location(in: textView)
            let position = textView.characterIndexForInsertion(at: location)
            textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(position, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please complete your great solution. The function now moves the cursor to the insertion point, but if you double click, it doesn't select the word, and if you triple click, it doesn't select the whole text.

Comment: I think `NSClickGestureRecognizer` isn't the right solution for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks @Willeke , do you recommend something else?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to know the style (attributes) of the line that has been clicked on, so I must use click gesture recognizer to recognize click location, then I can determine the attributes of that line/paragraph. That's why I'm trying to use NSClickGestureRecognizer

Comment: Can't you use delegte method `textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)`?